# How to harness control of my JQuery coded sliding divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Essentially I have 4 divs that take turns sliding in and sliding out with delays and then it recalls the function.  Like so:

```
$(document).ready (function bradslide(){

$("#slide1").delay('1000').slideDown('1000').delay('6000').slideUp('1000');
$("#slide2").delay('9000').slideDown('1000').delay('6000').slideUp('1000');
$("#slide3").delay('17000').slideDown('1000').delay('6000').slideUp('1000');
$("#slide4").delay('25000').slideDown('1000').delay('6000').slideUp('1000', 'swing',      bradslide);
}
);
```

Let me say that this works fine, but that I am open to cleaning it up or making it easier or more up to standard if suggestions are made.

However my question is this: How can I arrange this so that the end user can manipulate the animation.  This slides through the divs on its own, but ideally I would like to have a couple buttons to click to go backward or forwards (I think you get the idea).

Any suggestions of how or where to begin would be greatly appreciated.  I imagine I might have to scrap this little piece of code as it stands.  Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: You could write a small chapter on implementing an efficient and reusable slider, so I wouldn't anticipate too many sufficient responses. I'd suggest approaching it in smaller chunks, but you'd have to know what those chunks are, so it becomes circular! Either way, too large a question for the usual scope of SO, but maybe a kind soul will have something to say.

Comment: Fair enough, I appreciate the input anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite my own comment, I do have some general advice:

1. Look into using classes instead of IDs, and then use jQuery's DOM-traversal methods to identify what the next slider candidate is. Tracking the "currentSlide" and then targeting the "nextSlide" (identified with a `.next()` perhaps?) means that you can add any number of slider divs (with a class instead of ID, remember?) and still have it work.
2. The user controls (next, prev, or selecting a specific slide) simply interrupt the timer (probably a setTimeout instead of `.delay()`) and then invoke the exact same function that brings the next slide into place.
3. To make code more reusable and flexible, you should use some variables. For example, if your slide duration is going to be 1000, you would have `var duration = 1000` scoped to an appropriate place (the document ready function is fine... or the sliding function) and then in your function call (whatever it ends up looking like), you would use `.slideDown(duration)`. Then you can set that value to whatever you want and update it easily later.
4. Extending on the above, you could even build an API allowing you to pass values into your custom slider function:

```js
var bradslide = function(container, delay, duration) {
  // do stuff with a parent container, some delay value, and a duration value
};

bradslide('sliderParent', 6000, 1000);
```